# Coregistration of Sentinel 1 images

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am trying to align various Sentinel 1 image over an area with a similar path and row as the S1 images provided on GEE  are not coregistered. However, the values change of each image when inspected for before and after registration changes. Have provided the code. Can someone provide clarity on this?

I am doing this step of alignment so that I could draw pixel values by Feature in time.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Faakashchhabra7489%2FGEE%3ASentinel%201%20Align

Comment: the link does not lead to a script, please check again and use the "Get Link" option.

Comment: Hi Aakasha - my initial through is that the image(s) are being resampled during the registration process, which will change the values slightly. However, I can't tell for sure because I can't see your code - it appears your repository is not shared publicly. Can you either change the settings of the repo to share for viewing, or use the "Get Link" button to share a version of the script that is not tied to your repo.

Comment: Hi Justin, 
I have shared the accessible link. I observed that after using .reproject on the collection the pixels align together as per the master image however, when checked at the edges, the images aren't still aligned to each other. Is it because of the different dimensions of every image?

Comment: @AndyB - Posted the new link!

Comment: @JustinBraaten The values change when using bilinear or cubic technique and not the nearest neighbourhood. Cant we assign the nearest neighbourhood algorithm?

Comment: @AakashChhabra You need to click the "Get Link" button to enable a share-able link.
I am looking into co-registration on GEE now but not finding much help. Has there been any progress on this?